# How to call one view controller to another view controller After 1000 millisecond in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm new to iPhone development and I'm running `iOS` 6.1. I have two View Controllers called `firstViewController` and `secondViewController`. I need to call one view controller from another view controller after 1000 milliseconds without any click of a button, imageView etc.

How is it possible?

Comment: well, you should use 'dispatch_after' function where you can mention the  exact time delay.

Comment: Use PerformSelector or Timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code like this

```
NSTimer *timer;

timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(touchDetected) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];// because 1000 miliseconds=10 sec
```

In the touchDetected Method put your code

```
-(void)touchDetected
{
    LoginPage * loginPageObj=[[LoginPage alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginPage" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginPageObj animated:YES];
    [timer invalidate];
}
```

Here you can use code according to you like change the method name and ViewControllers name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: your answer is true ,but how to decalre LoginPage?

Comment: That's your  view controller you want to push. Please give here the name of View Controller you want to push. BTw sorry to be rude but you didn't check my answer carefully "Here you can use code according to you like change the method name and ViewControllers name." I have written

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(methodToCall:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1000.0];
```

Comment: your answer is true but how to call of one view controller to another view controller

Comment: SecondVc * ovbjSecondVc=[[SecondVc alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondVc" bundle:nil];  Now [ovbjSecondVc performSelector:@selector(methodNameinSecondVC) withObject:nil afterDelay:1000.0];

Comment: i hope you get it..:)

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
      [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(pushView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


     -(void)pushView {

         SeconViewController *SeconViewControllerObj=[[SeconViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SeconViewController" bundle:nil];
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:SeconViewControllerObj animated:YES];
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a `Selector (Method)` using `NSTimer` after a certain time using this -

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:<#(NSTimeInterval)#> target:<#(id)#> selector:<#(SEL)#> userInfo:<#(id)#> repeats:<#(BOOL)#>];
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a methode, lets call it

`-(void)pushNextVC;`

and the call

`[self performSelector:@selector(pushNextVC) withObject:nil afterDelay:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>];`

also possible are solutions with NSTimer, but for this the "performSelector" is enought :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(gotoNextView) withObject:nil afterDelay:]
```